# Checking openssl result in a dictionary attack

Tags: bash, openssl, darwin

i am struggling with a task assigned by my professor at university. The professor asks to do a dictionary attack to a cyphertext in bash, and i don't understand when my script uses the correct password.
The usage of the script is: `chyperscript.sh <cyphertext> <dictionary>`.
My first thought was

```
while read -r word; do
    if openssl enc -des3 -d -k "$word" < "$1" > decrypted.txt 2>/dev/null
    then
        echo "the word is $word"
        cat decrypted.txt
        break
    fi
done <"$2"
```

but it seems to be wrong. Thanks to who will answer.

Comment: And why _it seems to be wrong_?

Comment: can you shae more details on the problem and what is wrong.